# Where to force Catalina upgrade and not Big sur upgrade from Mojave?

Tags: catalina, mojave, upgrade, big-sur, downgrade

The [current link](https://apps.apple.com/app/macos-catalina/id1466841314?mt=12) from [Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683) is not working.
Apple try to force us to upgrade to Big Sur everywhere.
Where do we find the Catalina upgrade link ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you searched the app store for catalina?

Comment: Yes, no result sadly

Comment: This question has been declared a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos But it is outdated, and provide a none working link.